# Why does ApexPages.getMessages() return multiple Message objects for field validation errors?

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation

I'm using a standard controller with a command button that saves a record.  When one of the fields is invalid, the ApexPages.getMessages() function returns multiple messages like this:

```
19:36:58:445 USER_DEBUG [214]|DEBUG|*** ApexPages.Message["Invalid number"]
19:36:58:456 USER_DEBUG [214]|DEBUG|*** ApexPages.Message["My Custom Number Field: Invalid number"]
19:36:58:456 USER_DEBUG [214]|DEBUG|*** ApexPages.Message["My Custom Number Field 2: Invalid number"]
```

Is there a way to show only the `Field Label: error message` errors?

Comment: 'field invalid' - as in fails a Validation Rule? or as in you are using addError() method? or as in you are doing ApexPages.addmessage() in your code?

Comment: as in, built-in field validation.  no custom code adding an error.  this example demonstrates the error displayed when putting alphas into a numeric field.

Comment: Would it be okay to remove the `<apex:pageMessages>` element from your page? Then the top level messages will not be shown. I'd understand if this isn't an option though, another solution I can think of is to manually remove the top level error from the messages.

Comment: But if you have USER_DEBUG lines then you must be calling ApexPages.addmessage() in some controller code - perhaps in a catch block associated to a try with DML?

Comment: @Lex I don't have an apex:pageMessage component on the page.  crop1645 I am not calling addMessage().  I'm calling ApexPages.getMessages() and printing out each Message in a debug statement.  The messages are automatically added (by the standard controller I believe) when a field value is invalid